# Possible to make an Android Notification that does not call an Intent?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I need to put a Notification in the Status bar while my app is running, but I don't want it to call back to my Activity if selected.  Its meant to just be info to the user that the app is running - basically a reminder in case they press the home button and minimize it.

Ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just ignore the callback?

Comment: I thought that you had to pass in an Intent?  Or maybe I'm misunderstanding, how would my Activity not respond to an Intent?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - notification manager, having a notification without an intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040742/android-notification-manager-having-a-notification-without-an-intent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up coming up with a solution to this issue although its basically a hack.  instead of setting the intent to point to an Activity class I'm using a Dialog class.

```
this.notificationIntent = new Intent(this, SomeDialog.class);
```

Now if the user selects the notification, via the logcat, I can see the Starting Activity logged, but it appears nothing happens.

This allows me to post a notification that stays while my app is running and then I just dismiss it when the user exits.

Comment: Does not this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040742/android-notification-manager-having-a-notification-without-an-intent work for you ? Basically `new Intent()`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same desired behavior.  My solution was:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
```

Also, to make the notification automatically disappear when selected by the user

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);

or just

Intent intent = new Intent();